# iText PDF dont extract readonly fields in XML

Tags: xml, pdf, itext

I am extracting XML from PDF using **iText PDF java**. It works fine but skips **readonly** fields. Readonly fields are absent in generated XML. I am using following code to extract XML

```
public class PDFReadExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, TransformerException 
    {
        String SRC = "";
        String DEST = "";

        for (String s : args) {
            SRC = args[0];
            DEST = args[1];
        }
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PDFReadExample().readXml(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void readXml(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException, TransformerException 
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);

        AcroFields form = reader.getAcroFields();
        XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
        Node node = xfa.getDatasetsNode();
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
            if ("data".equals(list.item(i).getLocalName())) {
                node = list.item(i);

                break;
            }
        }

        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        tf.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        tf.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(os));
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I am not much familiar with PDF. Readonly fields are auto filled depend on input from other field. How I can extract readonly values in XML.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Sorry I cant share PDF. it is confidential.

Comment: In that case I don't see how to help you.